# I am trying to find the meaning of the word मासितरत्नों that i came across in shrimad devi puran can anyone please explain?

Tags: devi, devi-bhagavata-purana

जहां एक स्वर्णजटित, मासितरत्नों की आभा से मंडित मनोरम सिंहासन this is present in third skanda. I have already tried googling but have not found it .

Comment: It would mean valuable/precious gems.

Comment: It’s not मासित it’s भासित। the म and भ have been confused. भासित रत्न means shining gems/ gems with splendour or brilliance

Comment: Agree with @Archit it's भासित रत्नो and check the meaning of भासित here which means तेजोमय। प्रकाशमान। २. चमकदार। चमकीला                                                                                                   https://dict.hinkhoj.com/%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A4-meaning-in-english.words